# Determining if two goods are net/gross substitutes/complements from a utility function

Tags: microeconomics

Question: For the utility function U(x,y)=x^(2/3)y^(1/3), are x and y net substitutes, gross substitutes, net complements, or gross complements?

I'm having trouble understanding IF I need to derive the function or if there's an intuitive way of reaching the answer and HOW to derive the function if necessary. I've scoured the internet and read my textbook, but I can't seem to piece it together. Can anyone provide any insight please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q_x(p_x, p_y, m)$ and $q_y(p_x, p_y, m)$ be the Marshallian demands for good $x$ and $y$ respectively. Let $h_x(p_x, p_y, u)$ and $h_y(p_x, p_y,u)$ be the Hicksian demands for the two goods. Here $p_x, p_y$ are the prices for $x$ and $y$, $m$ is the income and $u$ is the utility level.

Goods $x$ and $y$ are **gross subsitutes** if:
$$
\frac{\partial q_x}{\partial p_y} >0 \text{ and } \frac{\partial q_y}{\partial p_x} > 0.
$$
$x$ and $y$ are **net substitutes** if:
$$
\frac{\partial h_x}{\partial p_y} >0 \text{ and } \frac{\partial h_y}{\partial p_x} > 0.
$$

As your utility function is Cobb-Douglass, we have that:
$$
q_x = \frac{2}{3} \frac{m}{p_x} \text{ and } q_y = \frac{1}{3} \frac{m}{p_y}.
$$
This should allow you to determine whether $x$ and $y$ are gross subsitutes (or not).

Next, to get the answer for the net subsitutes, you can use the Slutsky equation:
$$
\frac{\partial h_x}{\partial p_y} = \frac{\partial q_x}{\partial p_y} + \frac{\partial q_x}{\partial m} q_y,\\
\frac{\partial h_y}{\partial p_x} = \frac{\partial q_y}{\partial p_x} + \frac{\partial q_y}{\partial m}q_x.
$$
(Note that $\dfrac{\partial h_y}{\partial p_x} = \dfrac{\partial h_x}{\partial p_y}$ by symmetry of the Slutsky-matrix, so you only need to compute one of them.)